# Laplacian coupled with another equation over a two-dimensional rectangular region

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, elliptic-pde, differential-operators, linear-pde, heat-equation

I have the two-dimensional Laplacian $(\nabla^2 T(x,y)=0)$ coupled with another equation which is:

$$\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}+\alpha(t-T)=0 \tag 1$$

where it is known that $t(x=0)=t_i$.

The Laplacian is defined over $x\in[0,L], y\in[0,l]$ subjected to the following boundary conditions

$$\frac{\partial T(0,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial T(L,y)}{\partial x}=0 \tag 2$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,0)}{\partial y}=\gamma \tag 3$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,l)}{\partial y}=\zeta \Bigg[T(x,l)-t\Bigg] \tag 4$$

$\gamma, \alpha, \zeta, t_i$ are all constants $>0$.

---

**Attempt**

I solved $(1)$ using the method of integrating factor and substituted in $(4)$ to get the boundary condition in the following form:

$$\frac{\partial T(x,l)}{\partial y}=\zeta \Bigg[T(x,l)-\Bigg\{\alpha e^{-\alpha x}\Bigg(\int_0^x e^{\alpha s }T(s,y)\mathrm{d}s+\frac{t_{i}}{\alpha}\Bigg)\Bigg\}\Bigg] \tag 5$$

**Can someone suggest a way to handle the Laplacian subjected to b.c.(s) $(2), (3), (5)$ ?**

If there exists an alternate way to handle this coupled system, those suggestions are welcome too.

---

*Physical meaning*

The problem describes the flow of a fluid (with temperature $t$ and described by $(1)$) over a rectangular plate (at $y=l$) heated from the bottom (at $y=0$). The fluid is thermally coupled to the plate temperature $T$ through boundary condition $(4)$ which is the convection or Robin type condition.

---

Comment: What you can find out without solving anything is $t(L,\ell)=\frac{\alpha\gamma}{\ell}L$, by the divergence Theorem. But you probably want the full picture inside.